# docker in docker via bind mound - ubuntu

Tags: docker, docker-in-docker

I need to have an ubuntu image and then run a build process using that image. All is well until the build gets to the point of doing `docker build` etc.

Lets say I use the following to test this:

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
```

I then build that - `docker build -t ubuntudkr .`
Next, I run it like:

```
docker run -ti -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ubuntudkr
```

When I then run `docker ps` inside this container, I get the error `bash: docker: command not found`

All the examples I've found says I need to run:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
           -ti docker
```

They all use the docker image which contains the docker library. Is my answer then to install docker inside my base image to make it work? Does this then not go against what [docker themselves says](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)?

There are [many other](https://devopscube.com/run-docker-in-docker/) blog posts out there that gave the same advice, but my example does work. Where do I go wrong?

Comment: In general, a Docker image should be self-contained; if your application needs a `docker` binary then your Dockerfile needs to install it in some form.  (But also remember that being able to access the Docker socket means you can pretty trivially root the entire host; do you _need_ to launch more containers from inside a container, or can you use a safer approach?)

Comment: other containers won't be launched, no. This is for a CI build environment, so only need to run docker build and docker run publish commands will be run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the image `ubuntu:latest` in your dockerfile by the official `docker:latest` image wich contains docker binaries and does exactly what you want: https://hub.docker.com/_/docker

If you want to keep the Ubuntu image, you must install Docker tools following your error. By default, the Ubuntu image does not contain Docker binaries as a regular Ubuntu installation.